# PowerPivot Group By to find a count of values

Tags: excel, formula, powerpivot

I have a PowerPivot data model with thousands of rows and I'm trying to add a column that shows me the number of times a value occurs based on grouping the values in other columns.  For example, I want to count the total number of times an item has shown $ greater than zero for a dept by for each combination of item and date.  in the picture example provided here, 9 total stores show $ for the item for the specific date.  I'm looking to do this in a column instead of a measure so I can merge it with other data.  I have it solved as a measure with this formula:

```
CALCULATE (
  SUMX (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
      SUMMARIZE (
        Append1,
        Append1[UPC],
        Append1[Weeks]
      ),
      "NumStoresSell", CALCULATE(
        COUNT ( Append1[$] ),
        Append1[$] <> 0
      )
    ),
    [NumStoresSell]
  )
)
```

Any ideas on how I can solve it as a column?
thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This DAX formula will return the number of rows in a table that matches all three criteria specified, row-by-row.  The && means AND.  You can swap this out with || for an OR criteria.

This example is a formula entered into a table named Summary and counts the rows in a table named Data with the columns for Item, Transaction Date and Transaction Amount having values matching the formula's row in the Summary Table.

```
= CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Data),
        FILTER(Data,Data[Item]=Summary[Item],
                    &&Data[Transaction Date]=Summary[Transaction Date]
                        &&Data[Transaction Amount]=Summary[Transaction Amount]
                       )

                 )
```